# Pointers sequence in an c++ array of elements

Tags: c++

When creating an array in C++, are the elements of the array stored in a sequential location in the memory?

```
int* arr1 = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array

Comment: ?syntax error in line: `int* arr1 = [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are stored sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this allows you to use ++ or -- on a pointer for the array to move sequentially through the elements.

Comment: Not just increment and decrement (which do apply to pointer _variables_ only,  not to _any_ pointers) but all the pointer arithmetics.